# 'Strongly Typed' Generic Collections that hold any <T> of a given Interface/Class

Tags: c#, generic-collections

Is it possible to declare a generic collection to hold only objects implementing a generic Interface with any `<T>`?

My question burns down to: If I want to/have to store objects implementing a generic interface, is there a better way to express that fact than using a non generic collection or (generic of `<Object>`).

Example:

```
// An example Generic Interface
interface ISyncInterface<T>
{
    Task DoSync();
    IEnumerable<T> NewItems { get; }
}

// a manager-class that registers different classes implementing
// the generic interface.
// The code works - can it be done better?
class Manager
{
    private List<Object> _services = new List<Object>(); // <- works but is basically non generic
    // however the RegisterService() ensures that only correct types can be added.

    // would like to have something like below to indicate the Interface-Type
    // however: this would only allow _services2.Add to hold types of ISyncInterface<Object>
    //    - ISyncInterface<ServiceA_DTO> would fail.
    private List<ISyncInterface<Object>> _services2 = new List<ISyncInterface<Object>>();

    void RegisterService<T, U>(T service)
        where T : ISyncInterface<U>
    {
        _services.Add(service); // <- works e.g. for SyncServiceA 

        // _services2.Add(service); // <- FAILS for SyncServiceA - no conversion
        // _services2.Add((ISyncInterface<Object>) service); // <- FAILS also - no explicit cast
    }
}

// SETUP - The classes used above. Just to clarify.
class ServiceA_DTO { }
class ServiceB_DTO { }

class SyncServiceA : ISyncInterface<ServiceA_DTO>
{
    public Task DoSync() {}
    public IEnumerable<ServiceA_DTO> NewItems { get; }
}

class SyncServiceB : ISyncInterface<ServiceB_DTO>
{
    public Task DoSync() {}
    public IEnumerable<ServiceB_DTO> NewItems { get; } 
}
```

Is this possible at all? Any advice is highly appreciated!

Update: New, more verbose code to clarify the problem.

Below there was a suggestion to base the generic interface on an non generic one. But as a consequence all implementing classes of the generic interface would have to implement the non generic methods, properties etc. - or is there a way around it?

Thanks for your input!

Comment: What members does `MyInterface<T>` have? You might be able to make it covariant in `T` then you can create a `List<MyInterface<object>>`.

Comment: if the private List objects were private functions returning lists from <T> U would be able to set them = new List<T>() for return to process using them. If U are trying for a list to compare to the interfaces coming through then U would need to create that list in your constructor to be used, or create it in a compare function. If U are using a static list across all interfaces, you would need the static keyword on the item & also on the add process.

Comment: It's important to remember that each `MyInterface<T>` where `T` is different is a different class - think of them like `MyInterfaceInt` and `MyInterfaceString`. How would you create a class that can handle that? Instantiations of generic classes share implementation, not a type hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to declare a generic collection to hold only objects implementing a generic interface instantiated with *any* `T`?

Short answer: no.

Longer answer: no, because that is not useful.

Let's consider a simple generic interface:

```
interface I<T> { T Get(); }
```

And a bunch of objects that implement it:

```
class Lion : I<Lion> 
{
  public Lion Get() => this;
}
class TaxPolicyFactory : I<TaxPolicy>
{
  public TaxPolicy Get() => new TaxPolicy();
}
class Door: I<Doorknob>
{
  public Doorknob Get() => this.doorknob;
  ...
}
```

OK, now suppose you have a `List<I<ANYTHING>>` like you want:

```
var list = new List<I<???>> { new TaxPolicyFactory(), new Lion(), new Door() };
```

You've got a list with a tax policy factory, a lion and a door in it. Those types have nothing in common with each other; there's no operation you can perform on each of those objects.  Even if you could call `Get` on each of them, then you'd have a sequence with a tax policy, a lion and a doorknob in it, and what are you going to do with that?

Nothing, that's what. The constraint "implements interface `I<T>` for any `T`" is simply not a useful constraint in C#, so there is no way to express it.

It sounds like you have an "XY" problem. That is a problem where you have a bad solution in mind, and now you are asking questions about your bad solution. **Ask us a question about the real problem you have, not the bad idea you've got for its solution**.  What's the real problem?

---

UPDATE: With the new information in the question it is now much more clear. The feature you want is called *generic interface covariance*, which was my favourite feature for C# 4.

If you update your interface definition to

```
interface ISyncInterface<out T> { ... }
```

then you can use an `ISyncInterface<String>` in a context where an `ISyncInterface<Object>` is expected. For example, you could put an `ISyncInterface<Giraffe>` into a `List<ISyncInterface<Animal>>` or whatever.

**However** you are required to ensure that your interface definition *only uses `T` in a covariantly valid position*.  Your interface *is valid as stated*, but if for example you ever want to add a method `void M(T t);` to your interface, it will no longer be covariantly valid. The "out" is a mnemonic telling you that `T` can only be used as *output* of methods.  Since `IEnumerable<T>` is also covariantly valid, it's fine; there are no *inputs* of `T` in an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Also, variance only works with *generic interfaces and delegates*, and *the varying types must be reference types*. You can't put an `ISyncInterface<int>` into a `List<ISyncInterface<Object>>` because `int` is not a reference type.

There are many posts on SO about covariance and contravariance; you should also read the Microsoft documentation. It can be a confusing feature. If you're interested in the historical details of how we designed and implemented the feature, see my blog.

Comment: thanks for your input. Apparently my intentions where not clear from the example provided originally. I updated the code and provided a much more verbose example. 

My question burns down to: If I want to/have to store objects implementing a generic interface, is there a better way to express that other than using a non generic collection or (generic of <Object>) that expresses that fact better.

I did not find a solution, so I asked here...

Comment: @papa_bear: Are you asking how to achieve *generic interface covariance*? That's possible in C#; just add `out T` to your interface definition.  You can then put an `ISync<string>` into a `List<ISync<Object>>` or an `ISync<Giraffe>` into a `List<ISync<Animal>>` or whatever. However, you are required to obey the rules of covariantly valid interfaces should you do so.

Comment: @papa_bear: I'll add an update to the answer to that effect.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I read a few articles (co)variance and and this is what I was looking for - so I'll mark your reply as an answer.

One last question: as far as I understood the following rule applies:

As soon as I have an Interface with at least ONE in- or contravariant Type (e.g. `Interface Test<out TOk, TInvariant>{ .... }`
The ONLY way to store objects of different types in a collection is either to use non generics or the generic form:

`var objectsOfInterface = new List<Object>();`

Is this correct?

Comment: @papa_bear: See https://dotnetfiddle.net/BLhIPF for a simple demo.  You can store more derived instances and can implicitly cast to base types.  You can either use the collection directly (gives you everything) or use an interface.  Eric Lippert has explained why it does not make logical sense to have both on the same interface at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/12/03/exact-rules-for-variance-validity/  .

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try something like this:

```
  public interface MyInterface
  {//methods common to all types
    void FirstMethod();
  }
  public interface MyInterface<T> : MyInterface
  {//methods specific to a type
    void FirstMethod(T parameter);
  }
  public class MyClassThatHandlesAllInterfaces
  {
    private List<MyInterface> _allInterfacesT; //first interface in the chain
    public void AddInterface<T>(MyInterface<T> ifToAdd)
    {
      _allInterfacesT.Add(ifToAdd); // <- this is what I'd like to do
    }
  }
```

I use this pattern quite often.  Because I do not know all the details about your scenario it might not be suitable for you.

But it might help other people searching google.

Comment: It doesn't work if you need to return a value.

Comment: You can just change the signature of the interface to whatever methods you need